# How can I write down this symbol for volume in latex?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, mathtools, mathematics

I want to write down: [image] in a mathematical formula.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Difficult to say out of context. Maybe you want that “Vol” is a math operator that applies on “U(*k*)”.

In this case

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Vol}{Vol}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\Vol\op{U}(k)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OP means https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203836/volume-of-the-unitary-group (there wrongly typed).

Answer (score 2):

To me, it is unclear what you want. A variable like `U` is normally set in *italics* in a math context, as shown in the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

I want to write $\text{Vol } U(k)$.

I want to write Vol $U(k)$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is good. Try in the context of a theorem.

Comment: @egreg You are right (of course). I did not know in which context the question was set.

Comment: @c.p. Thanks for your kind words.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be rude. I'll leave it in: `U` is not a variable, but notation for the unitary group.